# Passing multiple values through RenderJson

Tags: go, revel

Learning 'go'. Is it possible to pass multiple values through RenderJson method. Something like :

```
return c.RenderJson(Response{Err: "", Results: {<a_struct>, <string>})
```

I know that you can pass one variable/value/struct like:

```
return c.RenderJson(Response{Err: "", Results: <a_struct>)
```

To achieve my purpose, I can create an struct of 'a_struct' and 'string' and the pass it along. Wondering if it can be achieved by passing muliple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel#Controller.RenderJson, RenderJson just takes an `interface{}`.  So I would expect

```
return c.RenderJson(
           Response{
               Err: "",
               Results: map[string]interface{}{
                   "a_struct": a_struct,
                   "other_thing": someString,
               },
           }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

Example from [Revel's manual](https://revel.github.io/manual/results.html#RenderJson):

```
// Simple example

type Stuff struct {
    Foo string ` json:"foo" xml:"foo" `
    Bar int ` json:"bar" xml:"bar" `
}

func (c MyController) MyAction() revel.Result {
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    data["error"] = nil
    stuff := Stuff{Foo: "xyz", Bar: 999}
    data["stuff"] = stuff
    return c.RenderJson(data)
    //return c.RenderXml(data)
}
```